# Dynamically setting the permission to a role

Tags: permissions, laravel-5

I am developing a authentication system that basically checks the type of user and redirects to individual page.

Basically there should be 2 types of account like:

Personal Account and Business Account

On business account people can choose a specific set of subscription while on personal account people should be able to upgrade

Each type of account has a set of specific permissions set by the administrator and the users would be able to do those sort of tasks only.

So how do I go about tackling this sort of problem with laravel. 
Right now I am manually checking by using

```
if($user->hasRole(['owner', 'admin'])) {

    //Redirect to the admin page 
}
```

//To check if the users actually has permission

```
if( $user->can(['edit-user', 'create-post'])){

//Create a post
}
```

Now what i need is i want the admin to dynamically set the permission and check the user type automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage permissions in middleware rather than another technique. what you can do is fetch the permission of authenticated users and you can check if user have permission or not for specific routes. that will solve your problem.